# Rewrite Rule exlude certain pattern

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Here is my current Rule. I'm not sure how to make it work.

```
RewriteRule ^/c/(.*)$ http://somurl/a/c/$1 [P,QSA]
```

my regular URL pattern is
    /c/one/two?somekey=somevalue

I need to exlude this pattern from being processed.

```
/c/one/two/ab-three/bc-four/cd-five?somekey=somevalue
                OR 
/c/one/two/bc-four/cd-five?somekey=somevalue
```

In the above patter, "bc" is consistent, this I need to check and exclude. Others may or maynot exist.

Will adding this condition above my rule work?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/one/(.*)/bc-(.*)/
```

If not can you help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

So we did something like this. Which works, but looks ugly! Any way to improve this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/one/.*bc-(.*)/
```